# Can I convert 3 class labels into a 2D array, in a multiclass classification problem, using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Can I convert, each class to this array shape-like?

`class 1 - [0,0]` `class 2 - [0,1]` `class 3 - [1,0]`

I have searched all sklearn documentation in label pre-processing, and I can only find encoding to a 3D array shape [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1].

Comment: Use the encoding you've found and cut off either the last or the first column?

Answer (score 1):

1. You could do this with `tensorflow.one_hot`, with 3 classes and depth of 2:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.one_hot([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0], depth=2)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

2. or `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` with `drop='first'`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')

ohe.fit_transform([[1], [2], [0], [1], [2], [0]]).toarray()
```

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 0.]])
```